# How to display records from Laravel via Vuetify v-data-table component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuetify-tabs

I have a project build in Laravel with Vue.js which work perfect statically, but I need convert it into dynamically to pull records from database table to v-data-table component.
I know Laravel and I know How these things works via Ajax/jQuery but I'm pretty new in Vue.js

Can someone explain to me how to display the results from the database in the v-data-table component.
Thanks.
Here is the Vue.js file:

```
<template>
    <v-app>
        <v-main>
            <div>
                <v-tab-item>
                    <v-card flat>
                        <v-card-text>
                            <v-card-title>
                                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                                <v-text-field
                                    v-model="search"
                                    append-icon="mdi-magnify"
                                    label="Search"
                                    single-line
                                    hide-details
                                ></v-text-field>
                            </v-card-title>
                            <v-data-table
                                :headers="headers"
                                :items="items"
                                :items-per-page="5"
                                class=""
                                :search="search">
                            </v-data-table>
                        </v-card-text>
                    </v-card>
                </v-tab-item>
           </div>
        </v-main>
    </v-app>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data: () => ({
            
            search: '',

            items: [],
            
            headers: [
            {
                text: '#',
                align: 'start',
                sortable: false,
                value: 'id',
            },

                { text: 'Name', value: 'name' },
                { text: 'Slug', value: 'slug' },
            ],
           
           /*THIS IS A STATIC DATA*/

            // items: [
            //     {
            //         id: 1,
            //         name: 'Test Name 1',
            //         slug: 'test-name-1',
                    
            //     }, 
            //     {
            //         id: 2,
            //         name: 'Test Name 2',
            //         slug: 'test-name-2',
                    
            //     },

            // ],
            /*THIS IS A STATIC DATA*/
    }),
    created () {
        this.getItems();
    },
    methods: {
        getItems() {
            axios
            .get('/test/vue')
            .then((response) => {
                this.items = response.data,
                console.log(response.data)
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error))

        },
    }    
}
</script>
```

And Here is Blade file:

```
@extends('it-pages.layout.vuetify')

@section('content')
<div id="appContainer">
    <software-template></software-template>
</div>
```

Output in the console is :
[console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iuls1.png)

Response from axios is also Ok

[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mC15C.png)

My Controller :

```
public function showData()
{
    $items = Category::select('id', 'name', 'slug')->where('order', 1)->get();
    // dd($items);
    return response()->json(['items' => $items]);
}
```

My route:

```
Route::get('test/vue', 'PagesController@showData');
```

console.log after changes axios lines
[console-log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8giBT.png)

Comment: What happens when you change `response => this.items = response.data,` to `this.items = response.data`?

Comment: Wait a second, your response is incorrect. Your server returns an object called `items`, while it should return an array of items. Show the response code in your laravel controller.

Comment: I can easily change the response in the controller, I'm just interested in how to display the response from the controller in the vuetify datatable component.

Comment: I put it in the controller to return any output so i can see it in response.
I will adapt it to the needs of the application on the server side later and that's not problem.
I just need to understand how to display this response from controler into v-data-table component.

Comment: The point is, your display code is correct, but your backend returns 1 object which your frontend cannot handle. Your backend should return an array of objects.

Comment: Oh thanks, I will modify beckend side and test it again.

Comment: I updated beckend and result is same.

Comment: Please update your question showing code from your backend

Comment: I updated my question, add controller and route code also.

Comment: Yes, that's beter. Now in your axios call change `post` to `get` to match your route definition. And make sure to make the adjustment from my first comment. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you Maarten. I changed axios call from post to get and I made adjustment regards to your first comment but still no luck

Comment: When I change response => this.items = response.data to this.items = response.data
I get error in console: TypeError: Cannot set property 'items' of undefined
    at app.js:2509, But I defined in data object like so items: []

Answer (score 0):

So there were multiple issues here:

1. The backend did you return a correct array
2. The frontend performed a `post` request instead of a `get`
3. The `this` context is not correct since you are using a `function` instead of `arrow syntax`

Make sure to look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions and read about how this changes how `this` is elevated.

In your case, you need to change the code on the `then` part of your axios call:

```
.then((response) => {
    this.items = response.data
})
```

Comment: I guess I have issues on the frontend side. When I modify lines of code in axios, console.log gives me an object instead of array and after that error says that prop type expected array got object. I will modify again my question with code which I have modified.

Comment: But now suddenly you have a `first ()` call in your eloquent query, this should be `get()`. You could have spotted that since again your console shows that `items` is an object instead of an array of objects, which is also the reason why vuetify throws the error.

Comment: Backend is fine. I was just testing this.
Does not work with either first () or get ()

Comment: I can change the question again if necessary with modified code but I only changed those lines in axios which you told me and test it with get() and first() in controller but either doesn't work

Comment: And Console show items as a object when I modify axios lines from response => this.items = response.data  to  this.items = response.data, but if I leave it as it was then it shows an array whether it is in the controller get() or first() Eloquent query

Answer (score 0):

I must to say that I solve the problem.
Problem was been in axios response.
Instead this.items = response.data I change to this.items = response.data.items and it work perfectly.

```
methods: {
        getItems() {
            axios
            .get('/test/vue')
            .then((response) => {
                this.items = response.data.items
                console.log(response.data.items) 
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error))

        },
    }
```